# How to build Android NDK .so without STL?

Tags: android, stl, android-ndk

I'm using the newest Android NDK r6b to build my shared object. This library does not use any kind of STL at all, but resulting .so includes many STL stuff like std::bad_alloc_what(void) and many more, which increases size of binary greatly. Also release builds include this garbage. APP_STL not defined anywhere, also the NDK r5b produces small binary with used functions only. Is it a bug of r6b? How can I build with r6b without STL stuff?

Comment: It's not a bug but we have to live with the fact: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19881

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a bug in NDK r6b and it always builds libraries with exceptions support, even if `-fno-exceptions` is explicitly specified.

See this question for details: [Android NDK produce unreasonable big binaries, how to optimize .so size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337232/android-ndk-produce-unreasonable-big-binaries-how-to-optimize-so-size)

Comment: I guess, you're right. It seems, that I should continue using an `old' r5 NDK. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using, say, `new` then you are implicitly using the standard library for the `std::bad_alloc` exception. Unless you call the no-throw version of `new`, which would instead use `std::nothrow`. If you don't use the standard library, then it won't get linked. Just make sure you don't, if that's what you want, or perhaps just move to C?

Comment: I'm sure I do not use STL anywhere, because as I've said, r5b builds the library without any STL reference.

Comment: @trashkalmar: So you don't even use `new` directly or indirectly in the entire code? Any chance r6b is building with exceptions enabled and r5b wasn't?

Comment: Of course, I'm using the `new` many times. How can I figure out whether the r6b turns exceptions on? And how to disable them explicitely? As far as I know, the Android runtime does not support exceptions in C++ code.

Comment: Well, `std::bad_alloc` is the exception `new` throws when is out of memory. Check for a '--no-exceptions' flag or similar.

Comment: Nothing changed. I assume its a bug in r6b. Anyway, thank you for answer.